# Per product tax configuration : is inclusive / is exclusive tax

Tags: php, magento

I want to add is inclusive or is exclusive configuration to per product basis.

Currently, Magento provides global configuration about catalog product price are inclusive: Yes/No.

Please check the screenshot.

http://prntscr.com/fxkrje
I want to do the that highlighted setting per product basis.

for ex:

Product A: Catalog price $1000 [INCL]

Product B: Catalog price $225 [EXCL]

Then My cart shows something like

http://prntscr.com/fxkuz4

It should be highlighted price for the second product due to its settings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve This Kind of functionality you have to use following Extension.

http://www.anowave.com/marketplace/magento-extensions/magento-tax-vat-switch-menu/

i already did This kind of functionality in my site

Comment: Sorry,

But it is not according to my requirement.

Comment: I need per product setting instead of per customer group.